# how to change the css to move the content right side?

Tags: javascript, css, html

http://www.fairprice.com.sg/wps/portal/fp/publicationsvideos

In this particular page,the content below the video should come right side of the video.
I tried by giving float:right as inline.It moved right side.
But the content didn't go up.
Help me how to do that.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `<p class="clear"></p>` from your HTML

```
<p class="videoframe"><iframe ...></iframe></p>

<!-- <p class="clear"></p> Remove this clear -->

<p class="corporate_vid">We Care, Lighting Up Lives - Volunteer Video</p>
<p class="clear"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<p class="videoframe"><iframe width="320" height="220" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JoPoBvtYWYQ" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
<p class="clear"></p> // remove this
<p class="corporate_vid">FairPrice Walks With U 2013 - Media Launch Highlights </p>
<p class="clear"></p> // don't remove this
<p class="videoframe"><iframe width="320" height="220" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AENK5bLDrt0" frameborder="0">    </iframe></p>
<p class="clear"></p>// remove this
<p class="corporate_vid">FairPrice Walks With U 2013</p>
<p class="clear"> // don't remove this
```

I mean the remove

tag between the class videoframe and corporate_vid,

```
 <p class="videoframe"></p>
    <p class="clear"></p> // remove this
 <p class="corporate_vid"></p>
```

but not between the corporate_vid  and videoframe class.

```
 <p class="corporate_vid"></p>
    <p class="clear"></p> // don't remove this
 <p class="videoframe"></p>
```